# Forwarding Postfix email to multiple users not working

Tags: email, postfix, forwarding

My /etc/postfix/virtual currently contains (emails obscured for privacy)

```
teals@example.com example+teals@gmail.com, other_example@gmail.com, third_example@gmail.com
example@example.com example@gmail.com
other@example.com other_example@gmail.com
shared@example.com example+shared@gmail.com, other_example+shared@gmail.com
@example.com example@gmail.com, other_example+shared@gmail.com
```

Forwarding for teals@example.com, example@example.com, and other@example.com work correctly, but for some reason any emails to shared@example.com disappear into the void.

I ran

```
sudo postfix reload
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
sudo service postfix restart
```

after editing /etc/postfix/virtual so virtual.db should be up to date (no errors).

Since the other emails (teals@example.com) deliver fine, I don't think it's an issue with firewalls or anything.

I RTFM'd the [virtual(5)](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html) documentation, but it's particularly light on details about forwarding to multiple addresses.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Comment: Yes, although I didn't really change anything. I must have had a typo, or forgotten to add my domain in main.cf under ```virtual_alias_domains```. Sorry I can't be more help!